# Inquiries about affiliation of some universities to US universities

Tags: united-states, university, education

In some countries, I have seen that some universities are affiliated to US universities. What is the meaning of this affiliation? Does it have any affect on the educational system and quality of that? For example, are the syllabus of courses in compatible with US universities?

Comment: I've seen enough different kinds of affiliations that this may be too broad. Everything from 'hey, you can do a semester abroad here easily' to 'we control and administer that site' and everything in between.

Comment: Perhaps giving some examples may help others explain the common features of this affiliation.

Comment: "are the syllabus of courses in compatible with US universities?" - this seems like it would have to be a specific question for a specific affiliated university pair, not something that could possibly be answered in general. If you're using this to decide whether you want to attend a particular school, you should analyze the specific relationship for that school and what it means to you rather than trying to make a generalization. Even if a feature applies to 95% of all such relationships, all that matters to you is the one specific one you're looking at which could be in the 5%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible meanings. Some examples:

Some universities have subsidiaries in other countries. I think that CMU has one in Qatar. I assume there are others.

Some universities have research affiliations with various other institutions in which resources are shared. Harvard has many of these. Some are devoted to specific topics, usually of importance to the affiliate; disease in Africa, for example. Click "Locations Abroad" at: http://worldwide.harvard.edu/harvard-world

Some universities might have an agreement to define how courses transfer between institutions. I don't have international examples but there are many such within the US.

Such affiliations may or may not be related to the educational mission, and may be more to the research aspects.

Other possibilities exist, for example international experience for faculty or graduate students or even general faculty sharing/exchanges.

---

For those not familiar with the US higher education system note that it is extremely diverse. There is no national system though some rules governing all, mostly to assure honesty and fairness. There are very different sorts of universities. Some, private ones, set their own policies. Some, public ones, adhere to rules set by a state, but differ from state to state and even within states. New York and Minnesota, for example, have (at least) three different sorts of public universities: Research, teaching, and junior/lower division colleges. The latter are two year institutions. The rules will differ to some degree among these different types. And some policies are left to the individual institutions even  then.